# how to do this simple PHP logic function?

Tags: php, variables

I need something like the following. but I don't know how I could achieve this. My script is

```
 <?php

 $id = "1";  //the value of $id is a number. 1 - 500

 $1 = "apple";
 $2 = "orange"; //this part contains an unique words based on id


 echo $1; //this part echo the unique word with respect to the id value

 ?>
```

When the id value is 1, I want it to `echo` the apple, if id = 2, the output should be orange, if the id value is 500 it should show the corresponding unique word. How can I achieve this? How can I write code for this function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use an array ?

Comment: Read these http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: variables can not start with number

Comment: Please share your actual code

Comment: I removed a bunch of tags that were completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as below :

```
echo $$id;
```

It will print exactly the same variable value which you want.

Comment: It think it is not possible to define variables starting by numbers

Comment: @vhjhgjhj Please select it as answer

Comment: Whilst double variables are a neat trick in PHP, they can cause problems if not properly controlled. I would prefer @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's answer.

Comment: This approach does work, but it is definitely not how people learn programming and PHP. Storing 500 separate variables in an unordered form can become uncontrollable. What if you need to add an item to the 1st position when you already have 500 variables? You will need to rename 500 variables one by one. If you miss an index key, you will need to read through 500 lines of code. And how are you going to check for a proper `$id` index?

Comment: @vhjhgjhj you have accepted the wrong answer. If you do this in anything other than trivial code you will regret it.

Comment: The main reason this is a terrible answer is that using a variable variable is hard to debug. You really need to use the upvoted answer that uses arrays instead. If you have a missing variable error in this answer, best of luck trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

You can use arrays.
Note that arrays are 0-based in PHP.

```
<?php

    $items = array('apple', 'orange', 'potato', 'whateverElse'); // you can store here all your 500 items

    $id = 1; // now, it is a number. in your case, it was a string.

    if ($id < 0 || $id >= sizeof($items))
        die("Incorrect ID");

    echo $items[$id];
?>
```

This script will output "orange".
You can change `$id` value and check results: If `$id` is between 0 and 3 inclusively, then it will output the corresponding item (0 - apple, 1 - orange, 2 - potato, 3 - whateverElse). Else, it will say that ID is incorrect.

Here is the [working Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/MhZ7Wj).

Answer (score 1):

You can as below :

```
<?php
$id = 1;
$arr = array("apple", "orange", "strawberry");
if(!empty($arr[$id - 1])){
    echo $arr[$id - 1];
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an array. Its way more simple.

```
$arr = array(0=>'apple',1=>'orange');
echo $arr[0]; // Outputs apple
echo $arr[1]; // Outputs orange
```

Answer (score -2):

you can simple do with this

```
 if($id==1){
      echo $1;
  }
 if($id==2){
      echo $2;
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure what scares me more - the original question or this answer. Are you going to make 500 if comparisons?

Comment: if i need to repeat this step for all my 500 id's to achieve this?

Comment: @vhjhgjhj use the second answer, it will solve your problem

Comment: This is unsuitable for the size of the problem this question asks. It would also be improved using a case statement.